# bottom sheet with layout inflation or on top of screen

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

I want to set bottom sheet with layout inflation. Means i want to add it programmatically after layout has been created.

I tried but not get successes. Write below code but bottom sheet not appears.

```
    View bottomSheet = getLayoutInflater().
            inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_search_pickup_location, coordinatorMain, false);


    // init the bottom sheet behavior
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);

    // change the state of the bottom sheet
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

Remember, I already know that **BottomSheetBehavior** is now working with **CoordinatorLayout** & layout must be added in xml file.

Updated: I added bottom sheet xml file for clarification.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/light_grey">

    </View>

    <View
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@color/light_grey">

    </View>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Where should we pick you up?"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_search_location">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgViewPickUpMarker"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/marker_pick_up" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgViewPickUpMarker"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imgViewPickUpMarkerSearch"
        android:text="Search for pickup location" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgViewPickUpMarkerSearch"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/places_ic_search" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgViewMap"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:tint="@color/translucent_black"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgViewMap"
        android:text="SELECT VIA MAP"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@color/translucent_black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:background="@color/ash">

</View>
```

Comment: share you xml code

Comment: you have created bottom sheet view..Did you added it to the main layout  your code shows its just inflated and not added to the view. your xml also misses the behaviour attribute which has to be added to the bottom sheet layout(LinearLayout). I recommend using BottomSheetFragment rather than inflating the views.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:behavior_hideable="false"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="44dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="360dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

           </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>




 bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet);

        request_show_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (bottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {

                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                } else {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Read the question carefully. I want to set bottom sheet with layout inflation. Means i want to add it programmatically after layout has been created.